# C-style macro compilation

Tags: c, compiler-errors, macros

I have the following macro:

```
#define oslock_TryAcquire(pLock) { \
        INITIALIZED_ASSERT(pLock) \
        acquire(pLock)}
```

While compiling I get :

```
error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
 #define oslock_TryAcquire(pLock ) { \
```

**Upd:**                                        ^
I get the "follow-up" error :

```
note: in expansion of macro ‘oslock_TryAcquire’
         if(!oslock_TryAcquire(&pLock)){
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I can`t understand what is a problem? Will be glsd to get advices

Comment: The problem is likely at the point you *use* the macro. Please include an example for that.

Comment: The error is probably in the context. The macro definition itself is correct. Please show a minimal source code that actually reproduces the problem.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] to show us. And include the *full* and *complete* error output.

Comment: Unrelated to the compiler error, you need a semicolon after each function call.

Comment: And there you have it... You can't have e.g. `if ({some statements})`, that's just not valid C. Some compilers have *non-portable extensions* that allows statements as expressions. For example [GCC have it](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs). I really don't recommend you use such extensions though. Remember, macros are ***not*** functions. Perhaps what you really want is an actual (possibly `inline`) function?

Comment: I removed the answer now that the code is clear. Not valid C code.

Comment: @Frankie_C Yep, better to wait with answering until the OP has clarified everything. After the edit, the problem became obvious.

Comment: I think you have call macro as function call , putting semicolon at last. As you have define macro as block do not put semicolon after calling macro . Or use do while loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macros are kind of a glorified text replacement. Your call

```
if(!oslock_TryAcquire(&pLock))
```

expands to

```
if(!{INITIALIZED_ASSERT(&pLock) acquire(&pLock)})
```

which is nonsense syntax in several different ways. Use a function instead of a macro.